# How do I permanently install VSCode Python plugin on remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have installed the Microsoft Python plugin on my local VSCode Insiders and haven't had any problems with it. But every time I open up a remote ssh session, I have to reinstall all of my plugins ("Install on SSH: localhost") and reload the session. This is a major problem for me because the restart often doesn't work and I get an error saying "Could not establish connection to 'localhost'." Is there a way to keep the remote plugins installed?

Comment: The remote plug-in has become much more stable since I wrote this, so this is no longer a significant issue for me.

Comment: Any solution to this question?

Comment: I have the same issue. 
I think that due to network slowness it is possible that vscode does not find your profile file and then decides to just reinstall from scratch with no plugins or whatever.
If you look in your .vscode/ you could see three sets of files starting with .alphanumericalcharacters.log .alphanumericalcharacters.pid .alphanumericalcharacters.token
Whenever vscode thinks it should reinstall it creates again those files and restarts the whole process of installing and completely ignore the exisitng installation.